# Zope component discrepancy between Interface(obj) and getAdapter(obj, Interface)

Tags: python, zope, zope.interface, zope3, zope.component

What could cause Interface(obj) to return obj, while getAdapter(obj, Interface) returns a properly adapted object?

Comment: Does `obj` itself already provide `Interface`?

Comment: Yes. It both implements() the interface and adapts() obj's class. I added those explicitly after the ZCML <adapter> tag alone exhibited this behavior.

Comment: `Interface()` returns `obj` if it already provides the interface, why would you need an adapter at all then?

Comment: Interface(obj) should return Adapter(obj). Instead it just returns obj. getAdapter(obj, Interface) does return Adapter(obj) though.

Comment: No, if `obj` already provides `Interface` (so `obj.__class__` implements `Interface`) then no adaptation is needed and `obj` itself is returned.

Comment: Sorry, I misstated things. Adapter implements(Interface) and adapts(obj.__class__). I am trying to isolate things down, but for some reason I keep ending up with this behavior. I've written dozens of adapters without encountering this issue, so it is a bit strange...

Comment: As stated, `IInterface(instance)` will not consult the adapter registry if `instance` already provides the interface. So your object is already providing the interface and does not require adapting. This is regardless of what adapters have been registered or not.

Comment: You need to think of calling-an-interface adaptation having similar semantics to a cast, that helps frame the idea of IFoo(myfoo) being not so dissimilar to list(mylist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a given instance already provides the interface, then `IInterface(instance)` will return the passed-in instance. After all, it already satisfies the requirement, you can use `instance` directly if you need to use `IInterface` methods:

```
>>> import zope.interface
>>> class IFoo(zope.interface.Interface):
...     pass
... 
>>> class Foo(object):
...     zope.interface.implements(IFoo)
...     pass
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> IFoo(foo)
<__main__.Foo object at 0x10eed22d0>
>>> IFoo.providedBy(foo)
True
```

`getAdapter()` goes directly to the adapter registry, and if you registered an adapter for the given class to `IInterface` then that adapter will be returned. This is somewhat pointless, since the original object already provided the interface, so no adaptation was needed.

Comment: You are 100% correct. I had declared that the object I was adapting implemented my Interface. I must have done it last week at some point and completely forgot. Thanks!